# What is the right way of generating cache-key based on multiple parameters?

Tags: php, redis

The two options I've seen used most often are:

```
$key = __METHOD__ . '(' . json_encode(['client_id' => $client_id, 'slug' => $slug], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) . ')';
$key = __METHOD__ . '(' . $client_id . 'ᐃ' . $slug . ')';
```

Which one should be preferred? The second clearly has advantage of less resource intensive processing. The first one produces more meaningful data, though of questionable value.

Is there a de-facto standard for generating keys based on multiple parameters?

Comment: i use myself ':' to delimitate parameters, mysite:cart:127:log or i use md5 mysite:cart:*a md5 hash* depending of the key, but yes hash the key name loose in visibility and is much ressource intensives

Comment: The reason I chose `ᐃ` rather than `:`, is because `:` is much more likely to be part of either of the parameter values.